# An alternative solution to using endswith()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this practice to solve but i dont' wanna use `endswith()` method how can i solve it  with  " str[i:j]  hint "

Given two strings, return `True` if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive"). Note: `s.lower()` returns the lowercase version of a string.

straightforward solution :

```
return a.endswith(b) or a.endswith(b)
```

Comment: Please provide input and respective output?

Comment: How about: `if a[::-1].startswith( b[::-1] ) or b[::-1].startswith( a[::-1] ): return True`

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey                                      
 'Hiabc', 'abc' → True
'AbC', 'HiaBc' → True
'abc', 'abXabc' → True

Answer (score 1):

You can assert that if you start at the end of each string and match them character by character, at least one of the strings will be exhausted without any differences:

```
def either_endswith(a, b):
    return all(a_char == b_char for a_char, b_char in zip(reversed(a), reversed(b)))

def either_endswith_case_insensitive(a, b):
    return either_endswith(a.lower(), b.lower())

# Positive
either_endswith_case_insensitive('aaaa', 'a')
either_endswith_case_insensitive('a', 'aaaa')
either_endswith_case_insensitive('aaaa', 'A')
either_endswith_case_insensitive('BbbB', 'BBbb')

# Negative
either_endswith_case_insensitive('aaaa', 'c')
either_endswith_case_insensitive('a', 'ccccc')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def end_other(a, b):
  if a[-len(b):].lower()==b.lower() or b[-len(a):].lower()==a.lower():
    return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def end_other(a, b):
   return a == b or a.lower() in b[len(b)-len(a):len(b)].lower() or b.lower() in a[len(a)-len(b):len(a)].lower()
```

one liner :)

in the case that a > b

we see if a the end of a we have b

(b in a[len(a)-len(b):len(a)]) we get len(a) - len(b) to  len(a)

that is the sameof len(b)

so it is true if the word is in that range

a == b is when the word is equal you don´t really need that

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

```
import re

# watch out if `b` contains escapable chars
# like \/ or ()
def test_if_a_ends_with_b(a, b):
    return re.search(r'{}$'.format(re.escape(b)), a, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Vanilla Python without import**

```
def test_if_a_ends_with_b(a, b):
    return a.lower().endswith(b.lower())

# or
def test_if_a_ends_with_b(a, b):
    return a[-len(b):].lower() == b.lower()
```

Comment: This should probably rather use `re.search` than `re.match`. With `match`, something like `a='foo', b='oo'` doesn't match, while the question sounds like it should. Also, why are the pure string methods *not recommended*? I just timed 10000 iterations over each of your options and the two you don't recommend were in average more than 5 times faster than the RegEx solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool(str2[::-1].lower().startswith(str1[::-1].lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def end_other(a, b):
  
  #converting strings to lower case
  a = a.lower()
  b = b.lower()
  
  if a.endswith(b) or b.endswith(a):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

OR

```
def end_other(a, b):
  
  #converting strings to lower case
  a = a.lower()
  b = b.lower()
  
  if a[-len(b):] == b or b[-len(a):] == a:
    return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def end_other(a, b):
  a = a.lower()
  b = b.lower()
  if len(a)<len(b) and a[:len(a)] == b[(len(b)-len(a)): len(b)]:
    return True
  elif len(b) < len(a) and b[:len(b)] == a[(len(a)-len(b)): len(a)]:
    return True
  elif a[:len(a)]== b[:len(b)]:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```